# how to do update and insert together in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to insert a record if it is not present with some data and if the record is present I want to update some of the keys of the data. But its not happening in $set and $setOnInsert is not working in this case.

```
db.update(
  {key1:value1},
  {
    $set:{key5:value5,key4:value4},
    $setOnInsert: { key1: value1,key2:value2,key3:value3,key4:value4 }
  },
  {upsert:true}
)
.then(out => {
    console.log("for out");
    console.log(out);
    return Promise.resolve(out);
})
```

Expected Result :-
It should modify key4 if the record is already there.

Current Result :-

Unhandled Rejection at: MongoError: Updating the path 'key4' would create a conflict at 'key4'

Answer (score 0):

You have key4:value4 in both $set and $setOnInsert. Remove it from $setOnInsert.

```
db.update(


 {key1:value1},
  {
    $set:{key5:value5,key4:value4},
    $setOnInsert: { key1: value1,key2:value2,key3:value3}
  },
  {upsert:true}
)
.then(out => {
    console.log("for out");
    console.log(out);
    return Promise.resolve(out);
})
```

Comment: thank you, i should have removed it from $setOnInsert